# Kill Holy Roman Emperor?

Tags: europa-universalis-3

In Europa Universalis 3, as Burgundy, I have been given the quest to gain the vote of Bohemia for Holy Roman Emperor. I figure that the best way to do this, since I already have 200 relations with them, no infamy, and high prestige, is to become the emperor first. I currently have secured the votes of all the electors of the Holy Roman Empire, except one. So I ask: is there any way for me to, say, "speed up" the death of the Holy Roman Emperor?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly. It depends if the Holy Roman Emperor has been turned into a general by the AI. If he has been made a general, defeating the force he leads in battle has a small, but significant chance to kill him. If he hasn't been turned into a general, then there is no way to speed up his demise.